How to write a python program that reads the text in a file and finds the word that appears the most?
Given the following code:
with open('python.txt', 'r') as python_file:
    word_file = (python_file.read()).split()
    x = len(word_file)
    wanted_word = word_file[0]
    for i in range(0, x):
        y = word_file[i]
        if word_file.count("y") >= word_file.count("wanted_word"):
            wanted_word = y

print(wanted_word)

(Note that the number of times answer word appeared is unique.)
The output (wanted_word) was the last word, not the correct one that appears the most in the 'python.txt' file.
Which part do I have to fix to get the right answer?
I think the problem is the variable 'y' in for loop which is not updating.. but not sure.

"y" with quotes is a string literal, a variable has no quotes. You compare the frequencies of the words "y" and "wanted_word", not of the words in the variables.

As @Michael mentioned, you need to use the variables in your if condition, otherwise you're just counting the words "y" and "wanted_word" (which probably have an occurrence of 0 if I'd have to guess).
with open('python.txt', 'r') as python_file:
    word_file = python_file.read().split()
    x = len(word_file)
    wanted_word = word_file[0]
    for i in range(x):
        y = word_file[i]
        if word_file.count(y) >= word_file.count(wanted_word):
            wanted_word = y

print(wanted_word)

However, you have another problem. I guess that you don't want to separate differently capitalized versions of a word. With your version you differentiate between "Hi" and "hi" although they are the same word. This extends to punctuation: The normal .split() splits whitespaces, therefore punctuation is split as part of a word, eg. "hi." and "hi" are counted as two separate words.
Furthermore, you can make your life easier by simply using collections.Counter().most_common() as documented here.
Here is a working example. You might need to adjust the character list that is replaced with spaces depending on your text and needs.
from collections import Counter

with open('python.txt', 'r') as file:
    text = file.read()

for char in '.,!?:;':
    text = text.replace(char, ' ')
text = text.lower()
words = text.split()
word_counter = Counter(words)

most_common_word, count = word_counter.most_common(1)[0]
print(f"Most common word: '{most_common_word}'")
print(f"Nr. of occurences: {count}")

A final note: If multiple words share being most common word, only the first occurring one is returned. This is the case in both of our versions.

Your code checks for the count of the string “y”, instead of the variable y. This is also true for the wanted_word variable. Instead use:
with open('python.txt', 'r') as python_file:
    word_file = (python_file.read()).split()
    x = len(word_file)
    wanted_word = word_file[0]
    for i in range(0, x):
        y = word_file[i] 
        if word_file.count(y) >= word_file.count(wanted_word):
            wanted_word = y

print(wanted_word)


with open('file.txt', 'r') as my_file:
    word_file = (my_file.read()).split()
    word_count = {}  # Dictionary to store word counts
    for word in word_file:
        if word in word_count:
            word_count[word] += 1
        else:
            word_count[word] = 1

    most_common_word = max(word_count, key=word_count.get)
    print("The most common word is:", most_common_word)

